# Displaying rectangle based on presence or lack of values in arbitrary column in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with multiple sets of data, but only one dataset. I've accomplished this by setting up multiple different columns in my table that SSRS uses. I set up a rectangle that contains a text box header and a tablix; the tablix is filtered on an identification column in the table so it only shows its own data. What I'd like to do is to only show each rectangle if there is applicable data.

I know that I can solve this problem by adding another row in my tablix and moving the text box title into it, and then showing or hiding the tablix based on whether or not it has data. That's probably the smart move. But before I did that, I wondered if there was a way to assign visibility to the rectangle based on the presence or lack of values in an arbitrary column in SSRS. First doesn't work, because everything other than the first rectangle has NULL in the relevant columns on the first row. Count doesn't work because the rectangle isn't actually hooked to data. What I'm looking for is something like a WHERE clause (=Count() where type = "ab" or something). Like I said, I can go with the tablix route. But the broader scope of this is the ability to control the presence on the report of various items based on the results that have been returned.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is better or worse than anything else, but I did just wonder about making the first row of my data contain the first non-zero item in that column. Then the First query will work.

Comment: How about a LIST grouped on your ID column with your tablix in it? No ID = no group

Comment: I'll see if I can get that to work, thanks.